# Как сделать двойное введение в строку

Tags: python-3.x

Например на калькуляторе как сделать чтобы в одну строку мы смогли вводить 3 значения т.е.

`5 + 5`

а не

```
Введите первое число
Введите логическое действие +,-,* 
Введите второе число
```

Comment: А в чем вы видите ограничение по вводу n значений вместо одного?

Comment: Принимаете всю строку целиком, а потом по пробелам разбиваете её на отдельные токены.

Comment: @Александр, если одной строкой, то можно вообще не разбивать, а просто `eval` делать)

Comment: @insolor, я тоже про eval подумал, но решил, что советовать его новичку - плохая идея.

Comment: @insolor чтобы вы посоветовали ??

Comment: Я советую парсить строку [рекурсивным спуском](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Реализации_алгоритмов/Метод_рекурсивного_спуска). Примеров калькуляторов в этих ваших интернетах - тьма.